# Google Drive API Quick Access

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Is is possible to get the list of documents in the users Google Drive Quick Access using the Google Drive API? I have been reading the Drive API but can't find any answers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can get the List of Documents. I hope you are looking for Java code as the tag mentioned tag is Java.

Here is Google Documentation to do all actions you need. I hope this helps.

[Google Drive API Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java)